# How to use scopes for associated collections in show and list actions in Rails Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

There is a method `associated_collection_scope` described [here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Associations-scoping), but it seems to work only for selects/multi-selects filtering. How to make it work for displaying collections in the list/show actions?

Comment: What do you mean by filtering the show action? denying access to certain records to some users?

Comment: No, I want to exclude part of records for all the users (for example these which are archived).

Comment: `associated_collection_scope` has worked for me. I needed to show a record in the dashboard only if its parent met a certain scope.

Answer (score 0):

To have a custom filtered list action you can define a single scope like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  scope :not_archived, -> { where(archived: false) }

  rails_admin do
    list do
      scopes [ :not_archived ]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It works perfectly, but only for resources that in the list, not for their associations that are displayed on this list. For example, you have a list of parents. Each of them has children. And what I want to achieve, is filtering these children in a list of parents (I don't want to display archived children).

Comment: You can make the SQL more complex and prefilter them. In this case in the not_archived scope you could make a join with the association and add additional where clauses to filter them also.